# Meteor: Disallow user from selecting id's when inserting documents

Tags: meteor

When using mini-mongo to insert documents into a collection a user could pass the _id field and that _id will be set on the document as long as it is a string or an ObjectID (and doesnt collide with an existing id). That doesnt seem sensible to me. I want the _id of the documents to be generated by the server, always, so I dont end up with a db where both strings (potentially of different length) and ObjectIDs exist as _ids.

Is there a simple way to achieve this? Right now the best I can think of is checking the id in a deny rule (where the _id will either already be set by Meteor or be the value the user provided) and if it's not the type/length I want it to be I change it, but that also requires checks to avoid duplicate ids. Not too difficult but seems overly complex for something as basic as this.

Comment: The reason for letting the client generate the `_id` field is probably to maximize the principle Latency Compensation, which is nice, but your concerns are the price we have to pay for it. However, since every document must have an `_id` field, it's obvious to me that Meteor should validate it for us. Too bad it doesn't :/

Comment: If you want the _id to come from the server then maybe the client is really only updating and not inserting.

Answer (score 0):

Reviewing my response, here's your answer:

Deny all inserts. Create a `method`, `collectionInsert(document)`, that checks if an `_id` field is specified.

```
Meteor.methods({
  collectionInsert: function(document) {
    if (document && document._id) {
      delete document._id;
    }
    // Returns the _id generated
    return collection.insert(document);
  }
});
```

In today's versions of meteor (0.8 and higher) the server and client generate the same `_id` in this case anyway. But using this method should ensure that the client simulates the field insert and that the server's version of the generated `_id` is authoritative.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this is probably to do the insert in a `Meteor.method`. You can't trust client-generated IDs in high-risk applications, so using `collection#insert` with `allow`/`deny` hooks isn't sufficient. Instead, call a method to do the insert, which will always create a server-generated ID.

You can still stub this method on the client, for latency compensation, but the inserted ID will be overwritten when the server call returns.